# How to redirect_to with custom to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model:

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}
  validates :user, presence: true

  def to_param
    "#{user.username}/#{name}"
  end
end
```

In #create action I'd like to redirect user to:

```
redirect_to @board
```

So for user `joe` who owns `boardname` board it would redirect to: `/joe/boardname`. Instead of that, it redirects to `/boards/joe/boardname`. Any idea why?

In my routes I have:

```
resources :boards, except: [:new, :show]
get '/new' => 'boards#new', as: 'new_board'
get '/:username/:name' => 'boards#show', as: 'user_board'
```

Comment: Should not you redirect to redirect_to user_board_url(@board)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand You want a username inside URL and You ensure that it's unique, right ?
Same goes to board.

First of all You user params is not very great, because it has slash inside and it's a special char. If You need both of those values use other separator like dash:

```
"#{user.username}-#{name}"
```

Secondly if You need to override Board param in URL You need to do the same inside Board model:

```
  def to_param
    name
  end
```

Then You need to adjust Your routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :boards, except: [:new, :show]
end
```

Now You should be able to use links like this:

```
redirect_to user_board_url(@board)
```

When user will open the url You used as an example, request will end up in `show` action of BoardsController with params:

```
{ user_id: "joe", board_id: "boardname" }
```

Be careful when using some custom values in `to_param`, make sure You escape those values properly.